# Отправка в Serial с задержкой в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, serial, qtest

Поставил перед собой такую задачу. На питоне при помощи *PyQt5* создал программу с *GUI*. 
В данной программе присутствует кнопка, при нажатии на которую в `Serial` отправляются данные из файла построчно. 
При этом, если очередная строка начинается с символа “**`z`**”, необходимо создать задержку отправления сообщения и эта задержка должна быть длиной в цифру, идущую после “**`z`**”, а потом продолжить отправление следующих строк.

Пробовал такую функцию для создания задержки:

```
def text_command():
    file = open('command.txt')
    commands = file.readlines()
    for line in commands:
        if line[0] == 'z':
            line = line.replace('z','')
            line = line.replace(';', '')
            line = line.replace('\n', '')
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(int(line), text_command)
        else:
            line = line.replace('\n', '')
            serial.writeData(str(line).encode())
    file.close

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(text_command)
```

Эта функция отправляет данные в сериал, а их, в сою очередь, принимает ардуинка и в зависимости от первого символа устанавливает определенный сервопривод в указанный угол.

При вызове моей функции, к сожалению, я не получаю нужный мне результат. Отправка строк происходит без задержки, соответственно, и сервоприводы принимают последнее отправленное положение.

В программе используются еще слайдеры, которые управляют положением серв
и они работаю хорошо, так что проблем с самой отправкой и приемом нет.

Как мне организовать подобную задержку?

На всякий случай содержимое файла

**command.txt**

```
a15;
b20;
c25;
z900;
a180;
b180;
c175;
z1500;
a0;
b0;
```

ОС Windows 7 
Python 3.8 
PyQt5 5.15.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку вы не предоставляете **`MRE`**, я покажу только простую демонстрацию:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

from PyQt5.QtTest import QTest                                         # +++ !!!


def text_command():
    with open('command.txt', "r") as f:                                # +                                
        commands = f.readlines()                                       # +

    for line in commands:
        line = line.strip()                                            # +
        
        if line[0] == 'z':
            line = line[1:-1]                                          # +
            print(f'Пауза: {line} мс') #            
            QTest.qWait(int(line))                                     # +++ !!!
        else:
            print(f'{line}')     # замените эту строку на строку ниже
#            serial.writeData(str(line).encode())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = text_command()
#    demo.show()
#    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли с моим вопросом. Сервы дергаются точно согласно командам в файле!

Comment: @AntonGricunov пожалуйста.